# Android : How to set the seekbar progress on increase/decrease of device volume and vice versa.?

Tags: android, media, device, volume, seekbar

In an android application, I want to set the device volume to the seekbar. Change in device volume has to change the seekbar progress and vice versa. Can anybody please help me to deal with this.?

**update 1** : 
This is what I have tried

1. Initialize `AudioManager`

   AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
2. Set device volume using

   if (mAudioManager != null) {
       mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume, 0);
       //volume - progress value from seekbar 
   }

Now this code updates the device's volume, if there is a change in seekbar value. But how do I update the seekbar value, if there is a change in device's volume.?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Ascorbin : Yes, I have tried. Plz check my update on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
MediaButton_Receiver mediaReceiver = new MediaButton_Receiver();
registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mediaReceiver );

class MediaButton_Receiver implements BroadcastReceiver {
     void onReceive(Intent intent) {

          KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent)intent.getExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT); 
          if (ke .getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || ke .getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
              // set the device volume
          }
     } 
}
```

I think it should help you :)

Answer (score 3):

**This is how I solved the issue..**

Overide `onKeyDown()` method in your activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // if one of the volume keys were pressed
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        // change the seek bar progress indicator position
        decreaseSeekbarValue();
    } else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        // change the seek bar progress indicator position
        increaseSeekbarValue();
    }
    // propagate the key event
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Please put your code of decreaseSeekbarValue(); and increaseSeekbarValue();